# Does pruning a decision tree always make it more general?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-trees, supervised-learning

If I prune a decision tree, does that make the resulting decision tree always more general than the original decision tree?

Are there examples where this is not the case?

Comment: Imagine pruning a tree all the way back to the root, would that make it more general ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you filter something out by choosing one branch over another branch in the tree, the observations you did not choose are forever lost.

But to directly answer your question - no, it does not always make it more general. If you construct a tree where all the decision are exactly the same, then pruning does not make it more general.